# Python API for VirtualBox

Tags: python, api, virtualbox

I have made a command-line interface for virtualbox such that the virtualbox can be controlled from a remote machine. now I am trying to implement the commmand-line interface using python virtualbox api. For that I have downloaded the pyvb package (python api documentation shows functions that can be used for implementing this under pyvb package). but when I give `pyvb.vb.VB.startVM(instance of VB class,pyvb.vm.vbVM)`

SERVER SIDE CODE IS

```
from pyvb.constants import *

from pyvb.vm import *

from pyvb.vb import *

import xpcom

import pyvb

import os

import socket

import threading

class ClientThread ( threading.Thread ):

   # Override Thread's __init__ method to accept the parameters needed:
   def __init__ ( self, channel, details ):

      self.channel = channel
      self.details = details
      threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )

   def run ( self ):

      print 'Received connection:', self.details [ 0 ]
      while 1:     
         s= self.channel.recv ( 1024 )
         if(s!='end'):
            if(s=='start'):
              v=VB() 
              pyvb.vb.VB.startVM(v,pyvb.vm.vbVM)

         else:
           self.channel.close()
           break
      print 'Closed connection:', self.details [ 0 ]


server = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
server.bind ( ( '127.0.0.1', 2897 ) )
server.listen ( 5 )

while True:
   channel, details = server.accept()
   ClientThread ( channel, details ).start()
```

it shows an error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/threading.py", line 486, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "news.py", line 27, in run
    pyvb.vb.VB.startVM(v,pyvb.vm.vbVM.getUUID(m))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pyvb-0.0.2-py2.5.egg/pyvb/vb.py", line 65, in startVM
    cmd='%s %s'%(VB_COMMAND_STARTVM, vm.getUUID())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getUUID'
```

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the full traceback.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check the official Python API from Virtualbox. pyvb seems like a wrapper written by a third party.

The virtualbox sdk contains Python examples and full API documentation.

Comment: This should get you started: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/SDKRef.pdf